# Refused edit trying to format in mathjax the content of an image posted by the op through a link

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Why has this proposed edit been refused for the question [Find the polar set P◦](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395385/find-the-polar-set-p)?

[image]

Comment: I don't know. I used my superpower to overrule the rejection. The given reason the rejectors picked didn't make sense to me. Mind you, it is not clear that the post would now be up to our standards, but that is IMHO tangential here. Your edit makes it easier for others to evaluate the question.

Comment: I noticed. Very thanks!

Comment: Here is link to the [suggested edit review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/856185) in question.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Yes, of course. Indeed I asked OP to edit the question by posting an attempted solution

Comment: @Martin Sleziak I was searching for it without success. Thanks

Comment: @trying You can find all your review on you profile page (under all actions/suggestion) - https://math.stackexchange.com/users/309917/trying?tab=activity&sort=suggestions. However, after Jyrki approved it, it is possible to find it also from [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2395385/revisions). (This is not the case for *rejected* edits. Still you can see them on [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2395385/timeline).)

Comment: This is not at all a relevant question anymore, as the asker of the question has since edited your edit, trying.

Comment: I agree with @amWhy in the sense that this question hardly serves a purpose any longer. On the other hand, I'm not sure that I cherish the prospect that everybody starts flagging wrongly rejected edits (the obvious alternative). Not all the cases will be clear cut, and diamond superpowers are not really needed :-/